# How to highlight the pie chart by default in apache echarts?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, charts, echarts

I want to highlight one part of the pie chart by default from apache echarts. I have added example link below and screenshot as well. Thanks in advance.

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-simple

[image]

Comment: I got the solution to highlight one part of the pie chart.
Answer: You need to add selectedMode as true and then selected: true inside the particular series.data object like below

  series: [
    {
      name: 'Access From',
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '50%',
      data: [
        { value: 1048, name: 'Search Engine' },
        { value: 735, name: 'Direct' },
        { value: 580, name: 'Email' },
        { value: 484, name: 'Union Ads', selected: true },
        { value: 300, name: 'Video Ads' }
      ],
      selectedMode: true,